# JavaScript chained builder with validation

Tags: java, javascript, validation, interface, builder

In this Java class, note how use of the constructor has been disallowed and replaced with an interface driven builder that guides instantiation and does validation

```
public class Position implements Serializable {

    private BigDecimal capital;
    private BigDecimal tolerableRiskInPercentOfCapitalPerTrade;
    private Direction direction;
    private BigDecimal pricePerUnit;
    private BigDecimal stopLossPricePerUnit;

    private Position(){}

    public final BigDecimal getTotalTolerableRiskPerTrade() {
        return capital.multiply(tolerableRiskInPercentOfCapitalPerTrade.divide(new BigDecimal(100)));
    }

    public final BigDecimal getStopLossPerUnitLoss() {
        if (direction.equals(Direction.LONG)){
            return pricePerUnit.subtract(stopLossPricePerUnit);
        } else {
            return stopLossPricePerUnit.subtract(pricePerUnit);
        }
    }

    public final BigDecimal getStopLossTotalLoss() {
        return getStopLossPerUnitLoss().multiply(getUnitsToBuy());
    }

    public final BigDecimal getUnitsToBuy() {
        BigDecimal result = getTotalTolerableRiskPerTrade().divide(getStopLossPerUnitLoss(), 0, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
        if (capital.compareTo(result.multiply(pricePerUnit)) != 1){
            return new BigDecimal(0);
        } else {
            return result;
        }
    }

    public final BigDecimal getTotal() {
        return getUnitsToBuy().multiply(pricePerUnit);
    }

    public static ICapital builder(){
        return new Builder();
    }

    public interface ICapital {
        ITolerableRiskInPercentOfCapitalPerTrade capital(final BigDecimal capital);
    }

    public interface ITolerableRiskInPercentOfCapitalPerTrade {
        IDirection tolerableRiskInPercentOfCapitalPerTrade(final BigDecimal tolerableRiskInPercentOfCapitalPerTrade);
    }

    public interface IDirection {
        IPricePerUnit direction(final Direction direction);
    }

    public interface IPricePerUnit {
        IStopLossPricePerUnit pricePerUnit(final BigDecimal pricePerUnit);
    }

    public interface IStopLossPricePerUnit {
        IBuild stopLossPricePerUnit(final BigDecimal stopLossPricePerUnit);
    }

    public interface IBuild {
        Position build();
    }

    private static class Builder implements ICapital, ITolerableRiskInPercentOfCapitalPerTrade, IDirection, IPricePerUnit, IStopLossPricePerUnit, IBuild {
        private final Position instance = new Position();

        @Override
        public Position build() {
            return instance;
        }

        @Override
        public ITolerableRiskInPercentOfCapitalPerTrade capital(final BigDecimal capital) {
            basicValidate(capital);
            instance.capital = capital;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public IDirection tolerableRiskInPercentOfCapitalPerTrade(final BigDecimal tolerableRiskInPercentOfCapitalPerTrade) {
            basicValidate(tolerableRiskInPercentOfCapitalPerTrade);
            if (tolerableRiskInPercentOfCapitalPerTrade.compareTo(new BigDecimal(100)) != -1) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("riskInPercent must be lower than 100");
            }
            instance.tolerableRiskInPercentOfCapitalPerTrade = tolerableRiskInPercentOfCapitalPerTrade;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public IPricePerUnit direction(final Direction direction) {
            if (direction==null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("argument can't be null");
            }
            instance.direction = direction;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public IStopLossPricePerUnit pricePerUnit(final BigDecimal pricePerUnit) {
            basicValidate(pricePerUnit);
            instance.pricePerUnit = pricePerUnit;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public IBuild stopLossPricePerUnit(final BigDecimal stopLossPricePerUnit) {
            basicValidate(stopLossPricePerUnit);
            if (instance.direction.equals(Direction.LONG) && instance.pricePerUnit.compareTo(stopLossPricePerUnit) != 1) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("price must be higher than stopLossPrice");
            }

            if (instance.direction.equals(Direction.SHORT) && stopLossPricePerUnit.compareTo(instance.pricePerUnit) != 1) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("stopLossPrice must be higher than price");
            }
            instance.stopLossPricePerUnit = stopLossPricePerUnit;
            return this;
        }
    }

    protected static void basicValidate(final BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
        if (bigDecimal == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("argument can't be null");
        }
        if (!(bigDecimal.signum() > 0)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("argument must have positive signum");
        }
    }
}
```

resulting in instantiation like this

```
Position.builder()
        .capital(new BigDecimal(10000))
        .tolerableRiskInPercentOfCapitalPerTrade(new BigDecimal(2))
        .direction(Direction.LONG)
        .pricePerUnit(new BigDecimal(25))
        .stopLossPricePerUnit(new BigDecimal(24))
        .build();
```

Trying to port code between languages isn't easy and identical functionality can't and shouldn't be expected. That said, are there any ways of emulating similar functionality in JavaScript? (vanilla or through some modules/libraries if necessary)

Comment: Side note: I see you're using a lot of `BigDecimal` in the above. JavaScript's native number type uses IEEE-754 double-precision values (like Java's `double` does) and therefore has the precision issues that `double` has. If those are a problem, you'll want to find a lib similar to `BigDecimal` for JavaScript (there are several choices, including [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/) [I haven't used it and can't vouch, but it's been around a while]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

One option is to do it almost exactly the same way: With a builder object that has methods to specify details and a `build` method (or similar) that you call to get the final object. The resulting call to build the object would look almost exactly the same (modulo type names and such).

Another option is to take advantage of JavaScript's object initializer syntax (aka "object literals") to have an "options" object that you pass into a constructor for the `Position`, like this:

```
function Position(options) {
    if (/*...the options aren't valid...*/) {
        throw new Error(/*...*/);
    }
    this.capital = options.capital;
    // ...
}
```

Usage:

```
var p = new Position({
    capital: 10000,
    tolerableRiskInPercentOfCapitalPerTrade: 2,
    direction: Direction.LONG,
    pricePerUnit: 25,
    stopLossPricePerUnit: 24
});
```

Inside the constructor, if you're going to use the data from `options` **directly** as properties on the new instance, you can use a function top copy them over:

```
function applyOptions(instance, options) {
    Object.keys(options).forEach(function(key) {
        instance[key] = options[key];
    });
    return instance;
}
```

Then:

```
function Position(options) {
    if (/*...the options aren't valid...*/) {
        throw new Error(/*...*/);
    }
    applyOptions(this, options);
}
```

(jQuery, if you use it, has an [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend) function that basically does this; Underscore, if you use it, has [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) and [`_.extendOwn`](http://underscorejs.org/#extendOwn).)

But if you're going to be doing some manipulation of the options before storing them as properties on the new instance, a blind copy like that wouldn't be ideal.